# ¿Como le hago para que funcione mi grid-template-columns?

Tags: html, css, grid

Tengo un problema con mi código ya que el CSS no se ve reflejado en mí HTML aquí les dejo mi código

```
<div class="camisa">
    <img  class="camisa__imagen" src="../img/3.jpg" alt="camisa react">
</div>
```

Y el css:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .camisa {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1f);
        column-gap: 2rem;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por su atención

Comment: Lee  lo publicado en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking y luego reelabora tu pregunta para poder responder.ç

Comment: en que parte de la pagina leo para poder resolver mi problema? me urge

Comment: Lee [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y por favor no coloques tu código como imágenes, pásalo a **bloques de código**. Un saludo :D

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Coloca en la pregunta al menos el código (no una imagen) de la sección head de la página, para comprobar que tienes enlazado el archivo CSS, por ahí puede ir el problema.

Comment: tengo enlazado el archivo css correctamente porque me funcionan todos los atributos que le añadido menos mi grid

Comment: Me marca un error al poner todo mi codigo html disculpen soy nuevo en programacion

Comment: Probablemente te da el error de que tu pregunta contiene demasiado código. Puedes agregar el código como [_snippet_](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet) para que a su vez se convierta en un [repro], en este caso. Además, para evitar ese problema, describe en la pregunta lo que esperas obtener y lo que estás obteniendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que yo veo es que le falta un r a la fracción del **`grid-template-columns`**.

Debería ir así:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .camisa {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 2rem;
    }
}
```